# My javascript clock won't display the time

Tags: javascript, clock

I am relatively new to javascript and I'm trying to code a simple web page with only a clock display in order to get a thorough understanding of the language. I am uncertain as to why the clock won't show up in the box. Can anyone point me in the right direction? The code I have is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>A Simple Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>
      A Simple JavaScript Clock
   </h1> 
   <form action="">
      <p><input type="text" id="time" /></p>
   </form>
   <script>
        "use strict";
        var tick =  setInterval("digitalClock()", 1000);

        function digitalClock() {

        var currentTime = new Date();

        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

        if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        currentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
        currentTime = document.getElementById("time");

       }

       window.onload = digitalClock();
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have any code in your file that would put the formatted date in a box.

Comment: As an aside, `setInterval(digitalClock, 1000)` (without quotes, without parens) should work just fine

Comment: instead of currentTime = document.getElementById('time') do 
document.getElementById().value = currentTime;

You aren't putting time to input.

Comment: Did you mean `document.getElementById("time").value = currentTime;`?

Comment: You need to alter the actual HTML! currentTime = document.getElementById("time"); should be document.getElementById("time").value = currentTime . See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: @FélixSaparelli: Not "work just fine", but rather "work much better". Passing strings is a form of `eval` and evil therefore.

Comment: Thanks, you guys! I knew I was getting hung up near the end and that the code wasn't putting the output into the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working code, You can set your function start execute when page on load. No need to quotes inside the setInterval function with braces. You can assign value to the inputs using its value property.

```js
        "use strict";

        function digitalClock() {

          var currentTime = new Date();

          var hours = currentTime.getHours();
          var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
          var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

          if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
          }
          if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
          }

          currentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
          document.getElementById("time").value = currentTime;

        }

        window.onload = function() {
          setInterval(digitalClock, 1000);
        };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>A Simple Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
      A Simple JavaScript Clock
   </h1> 
  <form action="">
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="time" />
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines:

> currentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
>     currentTime = document.getElementById("time");

to something similar to this:

```
// Creates a string which can be displayed in the box
var currentTimeStr = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
// Sets the value of the 'time' input to the time string
document.getElementById("time").value = currentTimeStr;
```